# Object dependencies in SSMS not reliable?

Tags: azure-sql-database, ssms

I needed to make an change to the definition of a table in a SQL Azure database.

This is a change which may cause problems to objects which reference this table. In SSMS, I have right-clicked on the table --> View dependencies to see which objects I need to check to see if they're going to be affected by my change.

However, in going through the list, I've found a couple of views which, based on their names, I figured may have a dependency on my table. I was correct - the dependency existed. However, these views were not listed in the Object Dependencies dialog box in SSMS.

This is making me concerned that there are other objects which have a dependency which I may have missed.

Why might this have happened? Can I do anything to make the dependency check more reliable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can I do anything to make the dependency check more reliable?

Call [sp_refreshview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-refreshview-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) or create the views with [SCHEMABINDING](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-view-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#schemabinding).

Here's an old, old trick every SQL Server DBA knows.  Run a query like this in SSMS

```
select concat('exec sp_refreshview ''', quotename(schema_name(schema_id)),'.', quotename(name),''';')
from sys.views
```

But use "Results to Text" CTRL-T or

[image]

Then copy the script from the results pane and run it.

You could also use a cursor and dynamic SQL, or in newer versions of SQL Server you can generate the whole batch and run it like this:

```
declare @SQL nvarchar(max) = 
(select STRING_AGG( concat('exec sp_refreshview ''', quotename(schema_name(schema_id)),'.', quotename(name),''';'), CHAR(13)+CHAR(10) )
from sys.views)

exec sp_executesql @SQL
```

Comment: Given that I have to pass the name of the view to sp_refreshview, and I don't know which views reference the changed table, I need to call it for every view. How do I do that?

Comment: See updated answer.